# How to sort day in R

Tags: r, date

For example I have a data frame:

```
  year month day
1 2006    12  29
2 2006    12  28
3 2006    12  27
4 2006    12  22
5 2006    12  21
6 2006    12  20
4 2006    11  22
5 2006    11  21
6 2006    11  20
```

I want to find the rows with max day in that month and year, so expect output to be:

```
  year month day
1 2006    12  29
2 2006    11  22
```

There will be 2007,2008 and etc.

I guess using aggregate group by but not successful. May I ask for help for this?

Thanks;

Thanks for all of your quick response! I have a follow up question here:
if I have 4 columns, e.g.

```
  year month day    value
1 2006    12  29    0.1
2 2006    12  28    0.2
3 2006    12  27    0.3
4 2006    12  22    0.4
5 2006    12  21    0.5
6 2006    12  20    0.6
7 2006    11  22    0.7
8 2006    11  21    0.8
9 2006    11  20    0.9
```

and want to get following output:

```
 year month day   value
1 2006    12  29   0.1
2 2006    11  22   0.7
```

Can I still use aggregate function?
Thanks;

Comment: What is the logic by which 22 and 29 December were chosen from the other days present in that month?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it's a typo. He meant `2 2006 11 22` for second row.

Comment: The raw data is for stock price traded at particular date. However, not all data is available, so I can only use the available data to do analysis. According to definition, we only process the price at the last day of each month, so I need to look for the 'Last' day available at each month.

Comment: Yes, just a typo. Already update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Data
year = rep(2006, 9)
month = c(rep(12, 6), rep(11, 3))
day = c(29:27, 22:20, 22:20)
value = 1:9
df = data.frame(year, month, day, value)

#   year month day value
# 1 2006    12  29     1
# 2 2006    12  28     2
# 3 2006    12  27     3
# 4 2006    12  22     4
# 5 2006    12  21     5
# 6 2006    12  20     6
# 7 2006    11  22     7
# 8 2006    11  21     8
# 9 2006    11  20     9

aggregate(day ~ year + month, data = df, FUN = max)

# year   month day
# 1 2006    11  22
# 2 2006    12  29
```

Left-hand side of `~` is the columns you are aggregating, and right-hand side if what you are *grouping by*. `FUN =` argument specifies the function you use to aggregate.

If you want the corresponding `value` to be also included in your aggregated data, you can use a combination of `aggregate` and `merge` like this:

```
merge(aggregate(day ~ year + month, data = df, FUN = max), df)

#   year month day value
# 1 2006    11  22     7
# 2 2006    12  29     1
```

Of course you can specify the arguments of `merge` to give you exactly what you want if you have more complicated datasets.

Comment: Just follow up this question, if df has 4 columns, month, day, year and value, I want to select the last day of each month and the corresponding value will also be kept. How to write that aggregate function?

Comment: @kaneroy I don't think you can do that with only `aggregate`, but you can with `merge` + `aggregate`. Check my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is great!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(year, month) %>% 
    summarise(day = max(day))
```